# Circuit that averages voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-design, voltage-measurement

Suppose we have an oscillating signal V(t) with V(t) >= 0. I'm looking for a circuit that averages this signal over a given time so that I can read out the average value directly using a simple voltage measurement tool.

Comment: Have you tried a [Low-Pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter)?

Comment: What rate of change does your signal have i.e. what is your averaging period?

Comment: @brhans: Thanks!

Comment: @Andy aka: In the best case, the averaging period would be customizable (which would be possible using a Low-Pass Filter).

Comment: Your "simple voltage measurement tool" could possibly be all you need. Most DC voltmeters have an internal low-pass filter and/or average this signal over a given time (just as you say) as part of their DC measurement. High-end DC voltmeters allow you to set the averaging period, so you can tune it to make sure you reject the time-varying component of your signal.